# MariaDB (MySQL) Event stopped working after years

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-event

```
CREATE EVENT `online` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 30 SECOND STARTS '2009-11-09 02:00:00' DO call  a7.main_online();
```

this event  stopped working after 6 years with no change. When I am looking on `mysql.event` table, I see `NULL` on `last_executed` column.

`EVENT SCHEDULER` is on.

I tried to recreate:

```
CREATE EVENT `online` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 30 SECOND STARTS '2015-11-09 02:00:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE disable on slave DO call  a7.main_online();
```

or

```
CREATE EVENT `online` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 30 SECOND STARTS '2015-11-09 02:00:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO call  a7.main_online();
```

still not work.

Tried to run `call  a7.main_online();` by hand to understand what can be happends: works.

Tried to look on `mysql.events` table: events on other DBs works.

I am using Mariadb 10.0.20, Debian.

Comment: Did you check if related `GLOBAL` variables are `SET`? Example: `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON` etc !!??

Comment: yes. the event scheduler is working  and other events are works.

Comment: Have you look in the logs (error / general) . The most events writing into

Comment: yes, I was looked into the event log, and I am seeing only Replication-related errors.